# I want to set the limit of maximum number of Tweets

Tags: python, twitter-streaming-api

I am very new to python. I'm using tweepy library to scrape tweets via twitter streaming API. but it seems like connection gets broken after running for an hour. I want to know if there is any way to stop the program from running before the connections get broken. In short limiting the tweets.

I have tried the .items method but it did'nt work as it gives the name Error.

```
  from tweepy import Stream
  from tweepy import OAuthHandler
  from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener


  ckey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  csecret="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  atoken="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  asecret="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

  class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        print(data)
        return(True)

    def on_error(self, status):
       print status

  auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
  auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)

  twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
  twitterStream.filter(track=["Obama"])
```

thanks

Comment: what is the error

Comment: thanks for replying "'Connection broken: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)', IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your connection issue take help from this:

[Tweepy Connection broken: IncompleteRead - best way to handle exception? or, can threading help avoid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48034725/tweepy-connection-broken-incompleteread-best-way-to-handle-exception-or-can)

To achieve tweets limitation you can `return False` from the class `def on_data` method, when the desired number of tweets are fetched. Set max number of tweets in the `init` method and use `try and except` for error handling. This might help

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.max_tweets = 10
    self.tweet_count = 0

def on_data(self, data):
    try:
     data
    except TypeError:
        print(completed)
    else:
     self.tweet_count+=1
     if(self.tweet_count==self.max_tweets):
       print("completed")
       return(False)
     else:
      decoded = json.loads(data)
```